# Tutology( DNF) and Contradiction ( CNF ) methods

Tags: java, math, discrete-mathematics

I need to make a method for CNF an DNF, though im having a difficult time understanding how to implement it in the code. Heres the problem

Method 1. Construct a Boolean expression in DNF for function defined by a given input/output table
(with at least one row with value 1).
To construct a DNF that has a given input/output table, identify each row in the table for which the value
of the function is 1. In the table above, these are rows 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6. For each such row, construct a
product that produces 1 (or true) for the exact combination of truth values of p, q, and r for that row and
0 (or false) for all other combinations of truth values of p, q, and r. For example, the product for the 1 st
row is pqr because pqr is 1 (true) if p=1, q=1, and r=1, and it is 0 for all other truth values of p, q, and r.
The product for the 2 nd row is pqr̅ because pqr̅ is 1 (true) if p=1, q=1, and r=0, and it is 0 for all other
truth values of p, q, and r. Similarly, the product for the 3 rd row is pq̅ r, the product for the 4 th row is pq̅r̅ ,
and the product for the 6 th row is p̅ q r̅ .Now, any Boolean expression with the given table as its input/output table has the value 1 (true) in case
pqr = 1, or in case pqr̅ =1, or in case pq̅ r=1, or in case pq̅r̅ =1, or in case p̅ q r̅ =1, and in no other cases. It
follows that a Boolean expression in DNF form with the given table is
pqr + pqr̅ + pq̅ r + pq̅ r̅ + p̅ q r̅ .

Method 2. Construct a Boolean expression in CNF for function defined by a given input/output table
(with at least one row with value 0).
To construct a CNF that has a given input/output table, identify each row in the table for which the value
of the function is 0. In the table above, these are rows 5, 7, and 8. For each such row, construct a sum that
produces 0 (or false) for the exact combination of truth values of p, q, and r for that row and 1 (or true)
for all other combinations of truth values of p, q, and r. For example, the sum for the 5 th row is p+q̅+r
because p+q̅+r̅ is 0 (false) if p=0, q=1, and r=1, and it is 0 for all other truth values of p, q, and r. The
sum for the 7 th row is p+q+r̅ because p+q+r̅ is 0 (false) if p=0, q=0, and r=1, and it is 1 for all other
truth values of p, q, and r. Similarly, the sum for the 8 th row is p+q+r.
Now, any Boolean expression with the given table as its input/output table has the value 0 (false) in case
p+q̅+r̅ =0, and in case p+q+r̅ =0, and in case p+q+r =0, and in no other cases. It follows that a Boolean
expression in CNF form with the given table is
(p+q̅ +r̅ ) (p+q+r̅ ) (p+q+r).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {

public static boolean DNF(int array[]){ // they all have to be true to be DNF

int counter =0;

for ( int x =0; x <= 8; x++){

//HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

    }//end for
return true;
}//end dnf




public static boolean CNF(){ // they all have to be true to be cnf

int counter = 0;
for ( int y = 0; y <= 8; y++){

//////////////////////////////////HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERRRRRRREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

    }//end for
return false;
}//end cnf



  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in);


    int myArray[] = new int[8];
    char p ;
    char q ;
    char r ;
boolean cnf = false;
boolean dnf = false;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int input;

    for(int variable = 0; variable < 8; variable++){
        System.out.println(" Enter 0 or 1 : ");
        input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input == 0 || input == 1){
                    myArray[variable] = input;
        }else if(input > 1){
            System.out.println("ERRRORRRRRRRR!");
            break;
        }else if(input < 0){
            System.out.println("ERRRORRRRRRRR!");
            break;
        }

    }


    System.out.println( "Truth Table" );
    System.out.println( "P \t Q \t R \t | f (p,q,r)" );
    System.out.println("________________________");
    System.out.println();

        for (i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 2 ; j++) {
                for ( k=  0; k < 2 ; k++) {

                    if ( i == 0) {
                        p = '1';
                    }//end if 
                    else {
                        p = '0'; 
                    }//end 


                    if (j == 0) {
                         q = '1';
                    }//end if 
                    else { 
                        q = '0';
                    }//end else



                    if (k == 0) {
                        r = '1';
                    }//end if 
                    else {
                        r = '0';
                    }//end else

                    //tutology = {i, j ,k};
                    System.out.println( p + "\t" + q + "\t" + r); 
                    //System.out.println( DNF(tutology) );
                    System.out.println();
                }//end for 

        }//end for
        }//end for
    }//end main

}//end main
```

Comment: Do what's the question?

Comment: *...I'm having a difficult time understanding...* Can you be more specific about what part you don't understand?

Comment: So im trying to figure out how to implement the CNF method and DNF method within the program to print out in the truth table, but im confused about how to code it.